# convergence to zero on compact subset

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$, and suppose $\lbrace f_n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $K$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then can we say by Cauchy's estimate $f_n^{\prime} \rightarrow 0$ on $K$?

Comment: Related: If a series of holomorphic functions, defined on an open set, converges to a function uniformly on compact sets, then the limit is also homomorphic, and the derivatives also converge uniformly on compact subsets to the derivative of the limit function. This fact indeed follows from the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: What is $\mathbb D$?. What do yo mean by Cauchy's estimates? Are you considering analytic functions?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f_n(z):=2^nz^n-1$ and $K:= \{1/2\}$. Then $f_n(1/2)=0 \to 0$ and $ f_n'(1/2) \to \infty.$)

Comment: are you choose $K$ only a point?

Comment: Yes. My $K$ is compact. Together wit $f_n$ we have a counterexample.

Comment: I saw another kind of my question in an article....only on that articale said $f_n$ convergence zero on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.....and then said by cauchy's estimate $f_{n}^{\prime} \rightarrow 0$